# missing data points in x axis when using lineplot in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm plotting some data that has dates and a score for each domain, so the x-axis has the dates, y-axis has the scores (0-10) and each plot is for a different domain.

My data has 13 dates (13 points on the x-axis,) but when plotting I only get 8 dates!

I've checked the input for the lineplot, and it has all 13 dates.

```
for domain in behaviors:
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.lineplot(x = 'submitted_at', y = str(domain), data = c53_behaviorl_T.iloc[0:13,:].reset_index(), lw = 3)
    ax.set_xticklabels(c53_behaviorl_T.reset_index().submitted_at,rotation=45)
    ax.set(xlabel = 'Date', ylabel = 'Score', title = domain)
```

This is what I get when running the input data:

```
question submitted_at        ...         water preference
0          2018-05-08        ...                        0
1          2018-05-21        ...                        1
2          2018-05-28        ...                        0
3          2018-06-06        ...                        0
4          2018-06-26        ...                        0
5          2018-07-27        ...                        0
6          2018-07-31        ...                        0
7          2018-09-12        ...                        0
8          2018-09-26        ...                        0
9          2018-10-12        ...                        0
10         2018-10-30        ...                        0
11         2018-12-06        ...                        0
12         2018-12-15        ...                        0

[13 rows x 20 columns]
```

but my line plot is stopping at date 7 (2018-09-12).

Comment: Will it work correctly if you remove `ax.set_xticklabels`? Can you provide a [mcve] (a self-contained, runnable code)?

Comment: using ax.set_xticklabels was the only wat that the rotation worked.

Comment: no, still 8 points :(